# Render two li side by side

Tags: html, css

Without changing the HTML how do i achieve the looks attached.

I want to render the name of the ingredient and the picture side by side currently it is just displaying it one top of other. I have attached an image of final output.

How do i just use css and make this happen ?

Thanks.

```
<ul>
        <li class="ingredient">
            <h3>Sourdough Bun Top</h3>
            <img src="./ingredients/sourdough_top.png">
        </li>
```

[image: Click here for Final Looks]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make the h3 `inline` like so:

```css
.ingredient h3 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="ingredient">
        <h3>Sourdough Bun Top</h3>
        <img src="./ingredients/sourdough_top.png">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey Jamie, your code works. 
But seems like i am doing something wrong with other codes and it doesn't work in mine but when i try it separately it works.

Comment: @Ashish There are many possible reasons. Maybe you have another "ingredient" class which conflicts with the one above. You can also try by using an inline-styling in the HTML. `<h3 style="display: inline">Sourdough Bun Top</h3>` ...

Answer (score -1):

Use this property in the `ingredient` class.

```css
.ingredient{
  display:flex;
}
```